# Unable to start thredds under tomcat7

Tags: tomcat7, thredds

I've seen similar posts, but none that seem to be similar enough to help. I'm running Tomcat 7.0.68 and Java 1.8.0_231 on CentOS 6.10 and so far have been unable to install thredds successfully. I followed the instructions at https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/tds/current/tutorial/GettingStarted.html#deploying, dropping the thredds.war file into the /opt/tomcat7/webapps directory, and while the thredds directory structure was unpacked, I could not hit localhost:8080/thredds, nor did the /opt/tomcat7/content directory get created.

Here's the pertinent snippet from catalina.out:

```
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.68
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Feb 8 2016 20:25:54 UTC
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.68.0
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Linux
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            2.6.32-754.23.1.el6.x86_64
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /usr/java/jre1.8.0_231-amd64
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_231-b11
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/tomcat7
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/tomcat7
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Xmx36864m
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Xms16384m
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat7/endorsed
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat7
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat7
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat7/temp
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 780 ms
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.68
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.68/webapps/thredds.war
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/opt/tomcat7/webapps/thredds/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Nov 14, 2019 4:11:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Nov 14, 2019 4:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/thredds] startup failed due to previous errors
Nov 14, 2019 4:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/thredds] appears to have started a thread named [Log4j2-TF-6-Scheduled-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Nov 14, 2019 4:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.68/webapps/thredds.war has finished in 33,195 ms
Nov 14, 2019 4:12:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.68/webapps/ROOT
Nov 14, 2019 4:12:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.68/webapps/ROOT has finished in 31 ms
Nov 14, 2019 4:12:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.68/webapps/manager
Nov 14, 2019 4:12:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.68/webapps/manager has finished in 27 ms
Nov 14, 2019 4:12:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.68/webapps/host-manager
Nov 14, 2019 4:12:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.68/webapps/host-manager has finished in 22 ms
Nov 14, 2019 4:12:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.68/webapps/docs
Nov 14, 2019 4:12:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.68/webapps/docs has finished in 18 ms
Nov 14, 2019 4:12:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.68/webapps/examples
Nov 14, 2019 4:12:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.68/webapps/examples has finished in 90 ms
Nov 14, 2019 4:12:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 14, 2019 4:12:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 14, 2019 4:12:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 33435 ms
```

I should note that I haven't been able to find the referenced "container log file", so I've run into somewhat of a roadblock. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

[THREDDS Data Server: Deployment fails in Tomcat 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160692/thredds-data-server-deployment-fails-in-tomcat-8) gave me the hint to look for a log file named "localhost.2019-11-14.log". In it I noticed this line:

`"tds.content.root.path" property isn't defined.`

Sure enough, thredds started successfully when I added this line to /opt/tomcat7/webapps/thredds/WEB-INF/classes/thredds/server/tds.properties:

`tds.content.root.path=/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.68/webapps/`

Comment: I do not recommend editing the tds.properties under the exploded webapps directory. This will disappear each time you upgrade the war file. You can set the location by passing the java property "tds.content.root.path" to the java instance running tomcat. In the documentation, we show how to do this using Tomcat's setenv.sh (https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/tds/current/tutorial/GettingStarted.html#running).

Comment: Good call. I've made the change to $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/setenv.sh